# select children for kindergarden group with binary linear programming

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

I have the following selection problem. I have some kids, each of them has some possible weekday-combinations when it could join a kindergarden group. Each weekday-combination has its own revenue (more days per week, more revenue). There are some restrictions on the maximum number of kids per weekday. Not every child has to be chosen . The aim is to maximize the total revenue. Here is an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(kid.nr=c(1,1,2,3,3, 3),
             kid.comb.nr=c(1,2,1,1,2, 3), 
             monday=c(0,0,1,0,1, 0),  
             tuesday=c(1,0,1,0,1, 0), 
             wednesday=c(0,1,0,0,1, 0), 
             thursday=c(0,0,1,1,1, 0), 
             friday=c(0,0,1,0,1, 0), 
             revenue.per.combn =c(100, 100, 400, 100, 500, 0)  )

# kid.nr 3 doesnt necessarily has to bee chosen

max.nr.kids.per.weekday <- c(1,2,3,2,1)
```

As far as I know, lpsolve could manage this binary linear progrmming problem? How could it be done? Especially, how do I cope with the fact that some kids have more than 1 posible weekday-combination, but each kid should only be considered once?

Comment: (When going for MIP): you typically introduce an variable KC: kid x combs (binary) which for kids ```1, 2, and 3``` is of size ```2, 1 and 3 vars```. Then you can introduce a constraint like ```<=1``` over the vars corresponding to one specific kid (at most one combination chosen).

Comment: @sascha please could you clarify your answer with a little example? I don´t know what KC means.

Comment: It's just a name. Just introduce 6 variables ```KC_i```, where ```KC_0 = 1 <-> kid 1 x comb 1 chosen```, ```KC_1 = 1 <-> kid 1 x comb 2 chosen```. Then put constraints on those. In general, if your real problems are bigger, you should check out alternatives first. I'm not sure, but it feels there might be a polynomial solution for this problem (max-flow min-cost and. co).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to develop a mathematical model. This can look like:

[image]

Then you need to implement this into R. I would suggest using the OMPR package.

Basically the wrinkle is the following: we have binary variables `x(i,j)` where `i=kids` and `j=daycombinations`. Now x(i,j) is somewhat "ragged": it does not exist for all `i,j`. E.g. `i=kid 2` has only one `j`. This type of thing can be handled by OMPR (they call this a "filter").

Comment: Thank you for your hints. I will have a lokk into the OMPR package.